# Callback function fires too early

Tags: jquery, callback, delay

I have this simple function in jQuery:

```
function detailspage(page) {

  if (page != checkcurrent) {

    checkcurrent = page;

    $('div#details').children("div").slideUp("slow", function() {

        $('div#details').children("div"+page).slideDown("slow");

    });

  };

};
```

I have put three `<div>`'s inside another `<div>` called `<div id="details">`, and they are all slided up and out of sight by default. I now wish to make each of them slide down, when a button for each of them is clicked. Of course a `<div>` that is open must first be slided up and out of sight, before the new one is slided down. That is why I have tried this simple callback function above.

(The `page` variable contains an id for one of the `div`'s, like `#info` or `#cast_crew`.)

But it doesn't work: [You can see the error by clicking the three buttons on the left in the bottom of the page, named "Cast & crew", "Info" and "Galleri"](http://www.nebulafilm.dk/productions/spor_8/).

It all works apart from the callback function that doesn't seem to cause any delay. The callback has no effect. I simply want the slidedown of the new box to start when the slideup of the current box is finished.

What is wrong? Why doesn't my callback work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I would take a look at the promise function in jquery to ensure all elements have completed the animation: http://api.jquery.com/promise/

For your example:

```
function detailspage(page) {
    if (page != checkcurrent) {
        // so we only have to search the dom once
        var details = $('div#details');
        checkcurrent = page;
        details.children("div").slideUp("slow").promise().done(
            function() {
                $('div' + page).slideDown("slow");
            });
    };
};
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cm3pv/6/

Comment: MAGIC! I was having the same issue as the OP. The callback just wasn't working like it's supposed to. It was firing immediately instead up waiting for `slideUp()` to finish. Tried implementing `.promise().done()` exactly like you're example and BOOM! Problem solved! Thanks :)

Comment: GREAT!! i know this is old but man i was looking for a long while trying to figure it out. I had this long post i was about to make when it came to me. "im probably not the one with this problem. Tried the .promise/.done and BAM! it worked PERFECTLY. Thanks

Comment: Any explanation to why passing the complete function as the second parameter, as suggested by the documentation, doesn't work?

Comment: Cy complete on fadeIn was firing few times. (console.log was fired up to 6 times). Promise() resolved my issues

Answer (score 3):

I tried Gary.S's accepted answer, but my function was still firing before the animation was complete. I found a suggestion on another post [How to get jQuery to wait until an effect is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065806/how-to-get-jquery-to-wait-until-an-effect-is-finished)

Needed to use `$.when( func ).done( function () { myFunc(); } );`

I HAD to put my function in a new function.

What I ended up using looked like this (to use your example):

```
$.when( $('div#details').children("div").slideUp("slow") ).done(){ function() {
    $('div#details').children("div"+page).slideDown("slow");
});
```