# jQuery. Text changes before animation. Incorrect order of effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

It's my first post so let me say Hello! everyone ;)

I have problem with animation. I would like to reach this effect:

1. show text "Lorem ipsum 1" and then animate it to 'opacity: 0'
2. run delay
3. change text to "Lorem ipsum 2" when it is not visible
4. show text using animate to 'opacity: 1'

But my code changes text on a very beginning. So I can't even see "Lorem ipsum 1".

I've tried to add .stop() and .queue() code but also doesn't work correctly(or I didn't use it right way).

I'll be appreciate for advise and explain why code is not execute step by step and how to get it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').append('<p>Lorem ipsum 1</p>');

  $('p')
    .animate({opacity: '0'}, 'slow')
    .delay(1000)
    .text('Lorem ipsum 2')
    .animate({opacity: '1'}, 'slow');
  });
```

Comment: Check the use of `callback` with `animate`. http://jsfiddle.net/9hrjX/

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery animate callback, to perform the following animation after first animation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').append('<p>Lorem ipsum 1</p>');

$('p')
    .animate({opacity: '0'}, 'slow', function(){
        $(this).text('Lorem ipsum 2')
        .animate({opacity: '1'}, 'slow');
    })        
});
```

Comment: It's alive!;) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have meddled with this before, and I found a post which is related to this problem: 
[How to get jQuery to wait until an effect is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065806/how-do-you-get-jquery-to-wait-until-an-effect-is-finished)

you simply put brackets behind your animation part. Code inside gets executed after the animation is done. This is called a callback function.

```
    $('p').animate({opacity: '0'}, 'slow', function() {
       //and here you put everything that should be executed after the animation
    });
```

I hope I didn't mess up anything.

Comment: It's alive!;) Thanks a lot!