# jQuery animate effect after animate effect, after animate effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
$("#page1 .textblock.hidden").fadeIn('fast').animate({
    'marginTop': textblockpan - ($("#page1 .textblock").height() / 2),
}, 1500, function () {
    $(".title").fadeIn(500, function () {
        $("#building").animate({
            width: "147px",
            height: "147px"
        }, 1000, function () {
            $("#info001").animate({
                width: "147px",
                height: "147px"
            }, 1000)
        });
    });
}).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
```

Found and a good startcode for some jQuery effects and learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065806/how-do-you-get-jquery-to-wait-until-an-effect-is-finished) how you should let one jQuery effect starts after a other. The code above works fine: my textblock animates in, the title is fading in and the `#building` div becomes bigger. So the first three effects show up in the correct order. But seems to be I lost control with inserting the fourth effect (animate `#info001`). Can somebody tell me if the code is looking fine or that indeed i lost my way in all the `){){{)){`?

Answer (score 1):

I can't spot anything wrong with your code, so I'm guessing the problem is elsewhere.  Make sure that `#info001` has some sort of layout that can take width and height (e.g., `block` instead of `inline`).

Comment: Thanks Derek, indeed my solution/fault was in the css. Thanks for the feedback!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add .stop() in front of .animate() and see.?

```
$("#page1 .textblock.hidden").fadeIn('fast').animate({
    'marginTop': textblockpan - ($("#page1 .textblock").height() / 2),
}, 1500, function () {
    $(".title").fadeIn(500, function () {
        $("#building").stop().animate({
            width: "147px",
            height: "147px"
        }, 1000, function () {
            $("#info001").stop().animate({
                width: "147px",
                height: "147px"
            }, 1000)
        });
    });
}).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
```