# Correct syntax for jQuery animate "complete" callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have to use a callback function when a jQuery animation is complete. I've always did that like this:

```
.animate({ properties }, duration, function() { /* callback */ });
```

However, when asking a question here I've been proposed a solution with a different syntax.

```
$('#redirectNoticeContainer').animate({ properties }, { queue: false, duration: 123 });
```

where am I supposed to put the callback function there? This is my guess, but it is not working.

```
$('#redirectNoticeContainer').animate({ properties }, { queue: false, duration: 123 }, function () {
console.log("ok");
setTimeout(function () { window.location.replace("/Account/Login"); }, 1200);
});
```

The animation works. Callback doesn't. Where should I put it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[That form of `animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) takes a `complete` option:

```
$("#redirectNoticeContainer").animate({
    // properties...
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 123,
    complete: function() {
        console.log("ok");
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.replace("/Account/Login");
        }, 1200);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use 'promises' since jquery 1.6

```
$('.play-button').animate({ opacity: 0 }).promise().done(function ()
{
     $('.video').addClass('playing');
});
```

See also [How to get jQuery to wait until an effect is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065806/how-do-you-get-jquery-to-wait-until-an-effect-is-finished)