# Switch page after jquery type effect

Tags: jquery

I’m a beginner and I’m wondering how to create a type effect (like these-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074399/what-to-choose-for-typewriter-effect-in-javascript) and have it go to another page upon completion (window.location.href = "page")... I don’t know how to connect the two?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question, but note that the first solution won't work for you if your typewriter effect doesn't allow you to specify a callback function (most don't).

[How to get jQuery to wait until an effect is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065806/how-do-you-get-jquery-to-wait-until-an-effect-is-finished)

Instead, I recommend the second solution using jQuery 1.6 promise() method.  So your code might look something like:

```
$(selector).teletype('slow');
$(selector).promise().done(function(){
    // will be called when all the animations on the queue finish
    window.location.href = "page";
});
```

Make sure you are using jQuery 1.6 or later.  Note that this requires that your typewriter effect is seen by jQuery as an effect.