# jQuery animate to transparent - easier solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to animate background from coloured to transparent. I have code like this:

```
$('.selector')
.animate({
        'background-color' : 'transparent'
}, 2000, function () {
        $(this).css({ 'background-color' : '' });
});
```

It is quite complicated, because:

1. I need to remove the `style=""` after the animation finishes, because otherwise the `style` would keep overriding the CSS class set by the `.hover` handler. So I used this trick: [jQuery - remove style added with .css() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4036857/684229)
2. I don't know of any neater way to wait for effects to complete in jQuery, see: [How to wait for effect queue to complete in jQuery call sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23141572/684229)

So, is there any simpler solution? Some more clever use of jQuery effects which wouldn't be so complicated?

I also tried the [trick with `.animate(,1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23141918/684229):

```
$('.selector')
.animate({
        'background-color' : 'transparent'
}, 2000)
.animate({'background-color': ''}, 1);
```

but it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @enapupe would you please be more verbose? Feel free to post an answer on that :-)

Answer (score 1):

css

```
.animated {-webkit-transition:background 0.4s ease;-moz-transition:background 0.5s ease;-ms-background 0.5s ease;background 0.5s ease;}
.selector {background:red}
.transparent_background {background: transparent};
```

html

```
<div class="selector animated"></diV>
```

js

```
$(".selector").addClass("transparent_background");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UEyc6/

Comment: Note that nowadays, prefixed css properties are still under development.

Answer (score 1):

Let CSS do the animation, and fallback to javascript when it's not supported with (for example) Modernizr: http://modernizr.com/

```
if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
    // Animate background color
    $('.element').addClass('animate-background-color');
} else {
    // use javascript animation.
}
```

And Your css:

```
.element {
    -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease-out 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 5s ease-out 0.1s;
    transition: background-color .5s ease-out 0.1s;
    background-color: rgba(121,123,123,1);
}

.element.animate-background-color {
    background-color: rgba(121,123,123,0);
}
```

Fiddle for the css animation: http://jsfiddle.net/c5PHf/

Comment: @TMS thats what Modernizr is for, it checks the support. If its not supported you fallback to javascript animations.
Heres the support: http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20transition